# SQL Write a request that returns: Customers - only who have had at least one order every day in the last month

Tags: sql

Dynamics of the number of orders by customers who created at least one order every day.

You have an `orders` table with columns `order_id` (order id), `created` (order creation date, `datetime` format), `user_id` (id of the customer who created the order).

Write a request that returns: Customers - only who have had at least one order every day in the last month.

Have you tried this, but don't know how to set a condition for every day?

Comment: Hi - which database are you using?
Also, what is your actually question? What have you tried and what issues have you encountered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select user_id
from orders
where created >= date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01')
  and created <  date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') + interval 1 month
group by user_id
having count(distinct date(created)) 
    = day(date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') + interval 1 month - interval 1 day)
```

How this works:

- the `where` clause filters on the previous month
- then we group by `user_id`
- finally, the `having` clause counts how many distinct days appear in each group, and ensures that it is equal to the number of days in the month; to compute the number of days within last month, we use date arithmetics: basically this is equal to the day number of the last day of the month

*Disclaimer*: I read this as a MySQL question, but now I see that there is no such tag in your question. The logic would be the same in other databases, you would just need to adjust the date arithmetics logic.

Comment: It should be show Dates too, for example: user_id  date count(orders)